# I have a problem with my python code, can someone help me to find the problem?

Tags: python, whatsapp

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Inicializar o driver do navegador
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Hybrid/Documents/PROJETO PAI")

# Abrir o WhatsApp Web
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

# Aguarde até que o usuário faça o login manualmente
input("Após fazer o login no WhatsApp Web, pressione Enter para continuar...")

# Lista de grupos de WhatsApp
grupos = ["Peo", "ds", "MAGAL"]

# Mensagem que será enviada
mensagem = "BOM DIA"

# Loop através dos grupos
for grupo in grupos:
    try:
        # Localizar o campo de pesquisa
        campo_pesquisa = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="3"]')

        # Digitar o nome do grupo
        campo_pesquisa.send_keys(grupo)
        time.sleep(2)

        # Pressionar Enter para abrir o grupo
        campo_pesquisa.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)

        # Localizar o campo de mensagem
        campo_mensagem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="1"]')

        # Digitar a mensagem
        campo_mensagem.send_keys(mensagem)
        time.sleep(2)

        # Pressionar Enter para enviar a mensagem
        campo_mensagem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)

        # Voltar para a tela inicial
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_1Ek-U"]')\
            .click()
        time.sleep(2)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erro ao enviar mensagem para o grupo '{grupo}': {e}")

# Fechar o navegador
driver.quit()
```

Comment: It is usually caused when the WebDriver instance (in your case, webdriver.Chrome()) is not being initialized correctly. Specifically, it means that the path you provided as an argument to webdriver.Chrome() is incorrect.

Comment: You should add the file name in the driver path.  eg.`driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Hybrid/Documents/PROJETO PAI/chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: For future questions, or if the answer below is insufficient, please include the full traceback and a more specific title. You can also add "print" statements to the code to see how far it got before the error. It is easier to debug when we know which line triggered the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/YOUR_PATH/chromedriver.exe")
```

you have to change drive address like above